# Tried to transfer eclipse workspace onto a hard drive now all classes have disappeared

Tags: java, eclipse

I bought a PC as I was unable to run MS SQL Server on my Mac. I copied my eclipse workspace onto a hard drive to transfer the projects over to my Mac to complete them. The classes have disappeared when I go to my workbench I can see the project files in the package explorer bar but they are all empty and unable to be opened.

Can I retrieve them?

Comment: do you mean *.class files or the *.java files

Comment: You have to import the project. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227903/how-to-transfer-project-written-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your source files were outside of the eclipse workspace folder file you copied. Use Windows explorer to search for any of the java files on your PC. If they are not there I'd say they are still on your Mac unless you deleted them.

Answer (score 0):

The workspace contains a subfolder `.metadata` which contain OS specific file paths which could be the reason for your problems. Try to **create a new workspace** and **import** your copied **projects**:

1. Switch to a new workspace: ***File > Switch Workspace > Others...***

   1. Enter new workspace location
   2. Click *Launch* (or *OK* when using an older Eclipse version)
2. ***File > Import...: General > Existing Projects into Workspace***:

   1. In ***Select root directory*** select the folder of your copied workspace
   2. Click ***Select All***
   3. Check ***Copy the projects into workspace***
   4. Click ***Finish***